# Как в цикле записать данные в массив VBA?

Tags: vba

Как при помощи цикла через диалоговое окно заполнить массив в VBA?

Само задание звучит так Дан одномерный массив А размерности N. Найти сумму элементов, расположенных между максимальным и минимальным.
Без подробностей
Как я понимаю надо в textbox внести длину массива и потом в программе через цикл записывать в массив числа которые вроде как надо считать диалоговым окном по очереди.
но опять же точных подробностей мне не дали

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Если массив уже дан - зачем его заполнять? Зачем диалоговое окно? Возможно, минимальное и максимальное - это не граничные значения массива, а  те, которые укажет пользователь? Например, массив от 1 до 100, но найти сумму с 25 по 31... В любом случае, здесь не решают учебные задания, здесь помогают разобраться с ошибками, проблемами, возникающими при решении задачи. Т.е. сначала Вы должны показать свои наработки.

Comment: Вам собственно дали задание, в котором самое разумное - придумать способ ввода самостоятельно. Я бы придумал текстовый файл, один элемент массива на строку. Его проще всего загружать. Если очень упёрлось иметь диалоговое окно - то используйте его для того, чтобы запрашивать имя файла с данными.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

тут нужно уточнение от вас: решить задачу через `Userforms`, или все-таки при помощи диалогового окна. Банальное решение, простой алгоритм. По сути вот ваше решение:

```
Sub Массив()
Dim A() As Integer
Dim dblSum As Double, dblProduct As Double
Dim intMin_value As Integer, intMin_index As Integer
Dim intMax_value As Integer, intMax_index As Integer
Dim intFrom As Integer, intTo As Integer, i As Integer, n As Integer
Worksheets("Лист1").Range("A2:G30").Clear
' создали массив
n = InputBox("введите количество элементов:")
ReDim A(1 To n)
For i = 1 To n
    A(i) = Int((10 - (-10) + 1) * Rnd + (-10))
    Worksheets("Лист1").Cells(i + 1, 1) = A(i)
Next


' Поиск минимального и максимального (по модулю) элементов.
    ' Сначала за минимальный и максимальный принимается первый элемент,
    ' затем остальные элементы сравниваются с ним и если будет найден
    ' новый минимальный или максимальный, то он будет запомнен и затем
    ' уже другие элементы будут сравниваться с ним.
' Двоеточие используется для удобства написания кода - чтобы можно было записать две команды в одну.
intMin_value = VBA.Abs(A(1)): intMin_index = 1
intMax_value = VBA.Abs(A(1)): intMax_index = 1
' Можно начинать поиск прямо с первого элемента, хотя в этом нет смысла,
    ' т.к. он уже проанализирован, но это проще, если вдруг вам надо будет
    ' работать не с одномерным, а двумерным массивом.
For i = 1 To UBound(A) Step 1
    If VBA.Abs(A(i)) < intMin_value Then
        intMin_value = VBA.Abs(A(i))
        intMin_index = i
    End If
    If VBA.Abs(A(i)) > intMax_value Then
        intMax_value = VBA.Abs(A(i))
        intMax_index = i
    End If
Next i

' Если минимальный и максимальный элемент (по модулю) - это один и тот же элемент,
    ' то расчитывать нечего, т.к. нужно считать между.
If intMin_index = intMax_index Then
    MsgBox "Между минимальным и максимальным элементом нет чисел.", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If

' Сумма элементов массива, расположенных между максимальным по модулю и минимальным по модулю элементами.
' Запись в переменную "dblProduct" единицы, иначе всегда будет 0, т.к. в пустой переменной
    ' с типом данных "Double" находится ноль.
dblProduct = 1
' Запись в переменные, с какой по какой элемент нужно двигаться.
If intMin_index < intMax_index Then
    intFrom = intMin_index
    intTo = intMax_index
Else
    intFrom = intMax_index
    intTo = intMin_index
End If
' Сумма элементов.
For i = intFrom + 1 To intTo - 1 Step 1
    dblProduct = dblProduct + A(i)
Next i

' Здесь в переменной "dblProduct" содержится результат, который можно вставить в эксель.

End Sub
```